# How can I filter an Interactive Grid based on a select list?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Interactive Grid that I'd like to be able to filter based on what a user selects in a select list. That would effectively change the SQL Query and refresh the Grid I think.

Seems like a Dynamic Action would be in order, but I'm not sure exactly how to get the Grid to update the way I want (i.e. either re-run the modified query or invoke another filtering mechanism).

Basically just trying to make it easier for users to filter rather than having them have to create a filter themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to create a Dynamic Action on the item driving the change (the select list). For the Dynamic Action, configure the settings as follows:

- Event: Change
- Selection Type: Item(s)
- Items(s): PX_ITEM_NAME

Configure the true Action as follows:

- Action: Refresh
- Selection Type: Region
- Region: *select the IG region*

Now, to tie the Interactive Grid to the item, go to edit the IG region and add a where clause that uses the item's value: `where col = :PX_ITEM_NAME`.

Finally, just under the SQL Query, look for **Page Items to Submit**. Be sure to put the names of any items that are used in the query and may change at run time (PX_ITEM_NAME in this case).